# JavaScript function stops working when it is moved to an external .js file

Tags: javascript, html, include, alert, script-tag

I moved a function from an html page to an included reference file.  It stopped working.

The complete contents of the file are:

```
alert('file included');

function doAlert() {
   alert('functions work');
}
```

In the html page, I have

```
<html>
<head><title>Page</title></head>
<body>
  HTML Template Header

  Some Content 

  ASP.NET MVC Partial View Starts
  <script type="text/javascript">
      doAlert();
  </script>
  ASP.NET MVC Partial View ends

  HTML Template Footer

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/wtf.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The 'file included' alert works, but the 'functions work' does not.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you include the file before you execute the function.

```
<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   doAlert();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should call your function(s) in the following way:

```
window.onload = function() {
    doAlert();
    // func_1();
    // func_2();
    // func_3();
    // ...
    // func_n();
};
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) for more information about the **window.onload** event.

[Code example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/proudlygeek/5rPV2/)

Comment: is there a way subscribe multiple functions to fire onload like a `+=` in C#?

Comment: @smartcaveman That's very easy to do, you just need to list them into the anonymous function: window.onload = function() { func1(); func2(); func3(); ... funcn(); };

Comment: what if you want to register them at different times?

Comment: @smartcaveman, what do you mean by "register"? Your functions will be called in order (func_1, func_2, func_3...func_n) from the anonymous function you've defined (See this http://jsfiddle.net/proudlygeek/s794p/)

Comment: You should (usually) only defer execution to the load or ready events on the window when the code is dependent on the DOM. Otherwise, if you're using load, it may disrupt the user's browsing experience because the code will not be executed until *every* resource is loaded.